# Solitarie card games are they on-topic?

Tags: discussion, top-7, on-topic

I think it is, they're valid solo card game.

Answer (score 10):

Solitary is single player game mode. Solitary mode has Agricola, Race For The Galaxy (with expansion) and other games. So it is on topic.